# Find Values in CSV that only Appear Once

Tags: csv, awk

I have a csv file with thousands of lines in it. I'd like to be able to find values that only appear once in this file.

For instance

```
dog
dog
cat
dog
bird
```

I'd like to get as my result:

```
cat
bird
```

I tried using the following `awk` command but it returned one of each value in the file:

```
awk -F"," '{print $1}' test.csv|sort|uniq
```

Returns:

```
dog
cat
bird
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. Try:

`awk -F"," '{print $1}' test.csv |sort | uniq -c | awk '{if ($1 == 1) print $2}'`

the `-c` flag on uniq will give you counts. Next awk will look for any items with the count of 1 (first field) and print the value of the second field ($2)

Only caveat is that this will return bird before cat due to it being previously sroted. you could pipe once more to `sort -r` to reverse the sort direction. This would be identical to the expected answer you asked for, but it is **not** the original sort order.

Comment: Only thing to be careful with: what if the first comma separated field contains spaces? Then the last awk in the pipeline won't give you the right output. I'd use `sed -rn 's/^[ ]+1[ ]+//p'`

Comment: yes good call @glennjackman! I was working with his sample input.

Comment: `... awk '$1==1{print $2}` is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

Just with awk:

```
awk -F, '{count[$1]++} END {for (key in count) if (count[key] == 1) print key}' test.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Cutting to first field, then sorting and displaying only uniques:

```
cut -d ',' -f 1 test.csv | sort | uniq -u
```

That is, if you append `-u` to your command, it'd work. This is just using `cut` instead of awk.

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option, this code is similar to @glenn jackman's:

`perl -F, -lane '$c{$F[0]}++; END{for $k (sort keys %c){print $k if $c{$k} == 1}}' test.csv`

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around each line of the input file
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace.
- `-e` execute the perl code
- `-F` autosplit modifier, in this case splits on `,`

`@F` is the array of words in each line, indexed starting with `$F[0]`